# Get current user windows MicrosoftAccount in node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, ntlm

In a node.js cli app running on a windows machine, you can get the current local user using:

```js
// method 1
const os = require('os')
console.log(os.userInfo())

// method 2
console.log(`${process.env.USERDOMAIN}\\${process.env.USERNAME}`)
```

Which outputs:

```sh
# METHOD 1
{
  uid: -1,
  gid: -1,
  username: 'adam',
  homedir: 'C:\\Users\\adam',
  shell: null
}

# METHOD 2
MYPC\adam
```

However, in modern Windows OS (e.g. Windows 10, 11), many users opt to sign-in with a Microsoft account. Apparently, this means there are 2 mirrored accounts on the machine:

- `{USERDOMAIN}\{USERNAME}` where `USERDOMAIN` could be the local machine name or the enterprise network domain name
- `MicrosoftAccount\{EmailAddress}` where `EmailAddress` is the Microsoft account username

How can I retrieve the 2nd variant of the username in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you can use the windows registry hive HCU, which maps to the current user hive and find the data you need somewhere in the hive, though I don't know the exact path.

Alternatively, you could try running some PS1 script/command that will get this information for you, but this method cannot be reliable, since this option (running ps1) may be disabled on some machines by the user.

And last but not least, you can always build a native Node.js extension, using C++ and access the native Windows API to do what you want :)

Comment: thanks for these suggestions. I'll probably go with the second one... definitely not the third!!! :-D

Comment: I will if I don't get any specific answers with an example. I've upvoted it for now. Thanks.

Comment: Also please check default env variables that Windows passes to your application, AFAIR there should be a user name.